# Understanding the derivation of the Poisson process.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, limits, analysis

I am learning about the Poisson Process and at the beginning of the proof, the following statement is left as an exercise for the reader:

> Let $N_{(a,b]}$ denote the number of random events in the time interval $(a,b]$. For $\alpha(t) = E(N_{(0,t]}), \lim_{t \to 0} \alpha(t) = 0 \implies \alpha(t) = \alpha * t$ for an $\alpha \ge 0$ and for all $t \ge 0$.

I realize this should be basic but I'm a bit rusty on my real analysis knowledge. Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you have the definition of $\alpha(t)$ correct? The definition you gave does not even depend on $t$. Did you perhaps mean $\alpha(t):=E[N_{(0,t]}]$ or something similar?

Comment: Yes I did. I'll edit the post.

Comment: And $N$ is supposed to be a homogeneous Poisson process?

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to be a homogenous Poisson process.

Answer (score 1):

The proof is using some properties of (homogenous) Poisson processes that are outside of your post. See the [wikipedia page for a Poisson process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process), under the section "interpreted as a counting process".

You need this property: $E(N_{(0,t]}) = E(N_{(a, a+t]})$, i.e., the process does not look any different if you shift the real number line to the left/right. This is the *homogeneity* that @Small Deviation is referring to. The size of the 'window' that you're looking at (given by $t$) matters, because a larger window will let you observe more points.

Now dividing $(0, t]$ into smaller windows of width $\Delta t$ each,

$$E\left(N_{(0, t]}\right) = E\left(N_{(0, \Delta t]} + N_{(\Delta t, 2\Delta t]}  + N_{(2\Delta t, 3\Delta t]} + \dots\right)$$
$$= E\left(N_{(0, \Delta t]}\right) + E\left(N_{(\Delta t, 2\Delta t]}\right)  + E\left(N_{(2\Delta t, 3\Delta t]}\right) + \dots$$
$$= E\left(N_{(0, \Delta t]}\right) + E\left(N_{(0, \Delta t]}\right) + E\left(N_{(0, \Delta t]}\right) + \dots $$
$$ = E\left(N_{(0, \Delta t]}\right) \frac{t}{\Delta t}$$

Thus, $\lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac{E\left(N_{(0, \Delta t]}\right)}{\Delta t}$ can be viewed as the 'expected average density' of points, which indeed does not depend on $t$. This limit would not exist (i.e., be a finite number) if we had $\lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} E\left(N_{(0, \Delta t]}\right) > 0$.